# MongodB issue on Mac OSX

Tags: mongodb, database

On OSX I was trying to run mongod, but it's throwing an error saying:

> Data Directory /data/db not found.

In `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`, path mentioned is `dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb`

So do I need to create `/data/db` again and if so why?

Comment: Try to add `--dbpath` option after `mongod`

Comment: or, run mkdir /data/db from terminal

Comment: @Alex  Thankyou, but what's this option "storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb" in mongod.conf file

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file located in /usr/local/var/mongodb.conf is sample  configuration file and is not being used by mongod. If you want it to be used, tweak it and pass it as argument to mongod when launching. e.g. `mongo --config /usr/local/var/mongodb.conf`

By default, MongoDB on Linux and OSX looks for directory `/data/db` to store it's database. See dbPath [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath) at MongoDB website.